# ListView: Unable To Change Image on Click

Tags: android, list, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, listadapter

I am attempting to change the Image in my ListFragment once the user clicks on the image in the list item. I had to implement a custom List Adapter as I had to load images during runtime. The list view image changes on clicking the image, but it is also changed for other items in the same position, while I scroll through the list. 
Please assist.

My adapter code is as follows:

```
public class PeopleAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private FindPeople activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
private static boolean imageLoadFinish=false;
private final Object semaphore = new Object();
ImageView thumb_image;
public PeopleAdapter(FindPeople followedActivities, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     activity = followedActivities;

     data.addAll(d);
     inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getActivity().getLayoutInflater();//getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView( final int position,  View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("getView", "getView Entered");
    final ViewHolder holder;
    imageLoadFinish=false;
       View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.found_people_row, null); //This should be your row layout
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Heading); // title
        holder.avatar=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.TypeIcon); //image
        holder.favIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.followIcon);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        HashMap<String, String> localhash = new HashMap<String, String>();
        localhash = data.get(position);

        String currenttitle = localhash.get("Name");
        String imagepath = localhash.get("avatar");

        holder.name.setText(currenttitle);

        if(!imagepath.equals(""))
        {

            holder.avatar.setImageBitmap(FollowedActivities.memoryCache.get(imagepath));

        }
        holder.favIcon.setTag(position);
        holder.favIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("Tag Position", ""+v.getTag());

    holder.favIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_512);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
}


static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView avatar;
    TextView name;
    ImageView favIcon;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

in your `getView()` change the following

```
if(!imagepath.equals(""))
{

     holder.avatar.setImageBitmap(FollowedActivities.memoryCache.get(imagepath));

}else
{
     holder.avatar.setImageBitmap("YOUR DEFAULT IMAGE");
}
```

Comment: The issue is not with my avatar image view. The issue is with my favIcon . The same is an Image view and on clicking on this icon the image view has to change to R.drawable.favorite_512. This change happens, but on scrolling down the list view I find that another favIcon is also changed to R.drawable.favorite_512, which I did not click. So I tried using Tags, but no effect. Please assist

Comment: Check solution of @Atul. i used the approach he answered with in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a boolean variable and set it to false in your Model class by default (FindPeople - from where I guess you are getting your data).

Then add it to your HashMap with key suppose "isClicked";

Then in the onClick method check its value before assigning the favIcon image,

```
holder.favIcon.setTag(position);
holder.favIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {            

        int position = (Integer) v.getTag(); //This will retrieve your clicked image

        HashMap<String, String> localhash = new HashMap<String, String>();
        localhash = data.get(position);

        if(!localhash.get("isClicked")){
           holder.favIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_512);
        }else{
           //The image was already clicked and changed
        }
    }
});
```

Try this out and let me know if it helps.

Comment: No it does not help. The items which I did not select are also changing as I scroll down. Any other ideas??

Comment: Can you post of what you tried? In case if a little piece might be missing?

Comment: holder.favIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     int pos = (Integer) v.getTag(); //This will retrieve your clicked image

           HashMap<String, String> localhash = new HashMap<String, String>();
           localhash = data.get(pos);

           if(!localhash.get("isClicked").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
              holder.favIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_512);
           }else{
              //The image was already clicked and changed
           }
    }
   });

Comment: Please check my comment above for the code change I performed, and in my Hashmap I added a new line as: rowData.put("isClicked", ""+false);

Comment: if(!localhash.get("isClicked").equalsIgnoreCase("true")) it will check for false. Change it to if(localhash.get("isClicked").equalsIgnoreCase("true")). Also after you have changed it change the value of isClicked to true so that next time you dont do it again.

Comment: I donot see the meaning there as I have set my data as rowData.put("isClicked", ""+false); so the value for localhash.get("isClicked").equalsIgnoreCase("true") will return as false and then the if condition will be valid and the enclosed statements will be executed. I have tried your recommendation as well, but then the image is not changed at all!!!, as the statement enclosed in IF condition is never executed.

Comment: Yup correct. Sorry for the above. Doesn't it run even for the first time?

Comment: It runs, and on click the image is changed, but on scrolling I find the image is changed for other list items, which I did not click, as well.